# Integrating Instagram API for android app

Tags: android, instagram-api

I like to allow users to login into instagram using webview and retrieve their username using the access token for the app am creating. The thing is my instagram dev account is in sandbox mode when i try to go live its asking to submit **"Video Screencast URL"**.Also i wont be using the instagram in websites so am little confused.

Answer (score 1):

On the submission page there a clear description about the video requirements:

> "Provide a link to a video screencast showing the experience in your app. Please show how your integration uses all permissions you are requesting, any interface to moderate content or getting rights to media, and any Instagram login experience. Since your app may be in sandbox mode, you can use data from sandbox users to showcase the integration"

If you are developing your app in Android Studio, the [Screen Record](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-video.html) option is exactly what you are going to need.